\n new line not working in Yahoo Mail using URL schema. iOS swift
In my app, I provide options for users to send emails through iMail, Gmail, Outlook, and Yahoo Mail, passing both subject and body via URL schemes with encoded data. I'm using the following function to encode the data, but I'm encountering an issue: in Yahoo Mail, \n is ignored, displaying all the data on a single line.
Is there anyone who knows how to encode \n specifically for Yahoo Mail?
This is the common function I'm using:
 func encodeUrl(_ string: String) -> String {
        print("string: \(string)")
        var queryCharSet = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        queryCharSet.remove(charactersIn: "+&")

        // Encode the rest of the adjusted string
        return string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: queryCharSet) ?? string
    }

For Yahoo, I've also tried:
func encodeUrl(_ string: String) -> String {
    let adjustedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>")
    var queryCharSet = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
    queryCharSet.remove(charactersIn: "+&")
    return adjustedString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: queryCharSet) ?? adjustedString
}

I've also tried double encoding and replacing \n with <br>, %0A, %0D%0A, and \r\n, but none have worked.
How I use encodeUrl function in Email.
func openEmailAppSelection(recipientEmail: String, subject: String, body: String, attachment: UIImage?, controller: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    
    // Make sure to encode the subject and body properly
    let encodedSubject = encodeUrl(subject)
    let encodedBody = encodeUrl(body)

    
    let emailApps: [(name: String, urlScheme: String)] = [
        ("Mail", "mailto:\(recipientEmail)"),
        ("Gmail", "googlegmail://co?to=\(recipientEmail)"),
        ("Outlook", "ms-outlook://compose?to=\(recipientEmail)"),
        ("Yahoo Mail", "ymail://mail/compose?to=\(recipientEmail)"),
        ("Spark", "readdle-spark://compose?recipient=\(recipientEmail)"),
        ("Airmail", "airmail://compose?to=\(recipientEmail)")
    ]
    
    let availableApps = emailApps.filter {
        guard let url = URL(string: $0.urlScheme) else { return false }
        return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
    }
    
    guard !availableApps.isEmpty else {
        openDefaultMailApp(to: recipientEmail, subject: subject, body: body, attachment: attachment, controller: controller)
        completion(true)

        return
    }
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: Constant.AppString.mailSelctionMsg, message: Constant.AppString.selectAnyOne, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    for app in availableApps {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: app.name, style: .default) { [self] _ in
            if app.name == "Mail" {
                self.openMailAppWithAttachment(recipientEmail: recipientEmail, subject: subject, body: body, attachment: attachment, controller: controller)
                completion(true)
            }
            else if let url = URL(string: "\(app.urlScheme)&subject=\(encodedSubject)&body=\(encodedBody)") {
                print("encoded url:\(url)")
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                completion(true)

            }
        })
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    controller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

Thank you in advance for any advice!

So you are using a ymail: URL? Doesn't the usage depend on what Yahoo decided?
